# Can only display SVG inline

Tags: html, image, svg

I am trying to display the same SVG in three different ways:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { SVGString } from "./svgString";

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<h1>SVG</h1>
<div class="pics">
  ${SVGString}
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(SVGString)}"></img>
  <img src="public/file.svg"></img>
</div>
`;
```

But only the first one (simply dumping it in as a string) works. The other two don't work, although the syntax appears to be correct. Perhaps there's something wrong with the svg itself. Below is the svg markup, as it appears in `svgString.js` and `file.svg`, but it would be more convenient to [look at the codepen.](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-stonebraker-k1hgrw?file=/src/index.js:0-257)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="350" height="350" viewBox="0 0 350 350">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="350" height="350" fill="#171512" />
  <g transform="translate(62.5,75)">
    <g>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="56.25" height="56.25" rx="50%" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="28.125" y="28.125" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="0" y="28.125" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
    </g>
    <g>
      <rect x="168.75" y="0" width="56.25" height="56.25" rx="50%" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="168.75" y="28.125" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="196.875" y="28.125" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
    </g>
    <g>
      <rect x="0" y="56.25" width="56.25" height="56.25" rx="50%" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="0" y="56.25" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="28.125" y="56.25" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="28.125" y="84.375" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
    </g>
    <g>
      <rect x="168.75" y="56.25" width="56.25" height="56.25" rx="50%" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="168.75" y="56.25" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="168.75" y="84.375" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="196.875" y="56.25" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
    </g>
    <g>
      <rect x="56.25" y="56.25" width="56.25" height="56.25" rx="50%" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="56.25" y="56.25" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="56.25" y="84.375" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="84.375" y="56.25" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="84.375" y="84.375" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
    </g>
    <g>
      <rect x="112.5" y="56.25" width="56.25" height="56.25" rx="50%" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="112.5" y="56.25" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="112.5" y="84.375" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="140.625" y="56.25" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="140.625" y="84.375" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
    </g>
    <g>
      <rect x="56.25" y="168.75" width="56.25" height="56.25" rx="50%" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="84.375" y="168.75" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="84.375" y="196.875" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
    </g>
    <g>
      <rect x="112.5" y="168.75" width="56.25" height="56.25" rx="50%" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="112.5" y="168.75" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="112.5" y="196.875" width="28.125" height="28.125" fill="#8C69EC" />
    </g>
    <g>
      <rect x="0" y="53.125" width="56.25" height="6.25" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="168.75" y="53.125" width="56.25" height="6.25" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="165.625" y="56.25" width="6.25" height="56.25" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="53.125" y="56.25" width="6.25" height="56.25" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="109.375" y="56.25" width="6.25" height="56.25" fill="#8C69EC" />
      <rect x="109.375" y="168.75" width="6.25" height="56.25" fill="#8C69EC" />
    </g>
    <g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Look at the second-to-last line of the SVG. That should be a closing `</g>` tag, not an opening one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pasted your svg into https://www.svgviewer.dev/. It says that your closing  tag is missing. Looks like -ccprog has the right idea. Change the second to the last line from <g> to </g>".